# Play local files via AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avkit

I try to play videos from user's library using their's paths, code getting path looks like :

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
if let dirPath = paths.first{
 let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(nameOfFile)
 print(videoURL)

 file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C56C205-1EFB-4ED5-AB79-93DFF78BD13F/Documents/2ED7F932-201E-4CF1-8002-16BB5DD554A4_L0_001
 completion(videoURL)
}
```

AVPlayer doesn't play these videos, but when I try to play video with remote url, it works fine and player plays. Code of AVPlayer is written with medium tutorial, so there could be problem with url. How to transform this path to make it playable?

Comment: are you sure you have a video kept locally? are you able to see any logs in console?

Comment: I save in local database filePaths only, not AVAssets, video path is saved there and method FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) returns true

Comment: Is the file extension missing in the path?